# My pillbugs are having trouble moulting

Tags: health, terrariums

I raise a box of about 30 pillbugs. About 2 months ago I found a bug that couldn't seem the moult. Its old skin was still attached to its body, and it was limping around with the skin on. It died after about a day.

In the following weeks, I found another bug like that, sitting out in the open with its old skin stuck on, making no attempt to moult. I tried to scrape off its skin very gently, but I couldn't do much and it died soon after.

Today I found a third bug like this. Am I not giving them the correct habitat to moult?

Photo shows the bug in question, looking sad and helpless (it's a bit wet as I had just watered the box).

**Environment**: It's currently the middle of winter (about 2-15 degrees celsius). I keep the bugs indoors in a room that is sometimes heated. They live in a little box placed in the shade, and I sprinkle a little water on the soil daily. The pillbugs eat a diet of dry and fresh leaves, carrots, and sometimes a piece of cat kibble.

[image: pillbug not moulting]

Comment: People keep pillbugs as pets?

Comment: It's like raising a dog, except they don't cost you $800 vet trips, they don't need to be walked, they don't poop on the sidewalk, and if you screw up and kill them, the SPCA doesn't get mad at you :)